# Patching brick, lath and plaster - electrical box

Tags: drywall, masonry, remodeling, patching-drywall, lath-and-plaster

[image: box within brick]

How do patch this? The box is within brick covered by lath and plaster.

How do I attach the box to make sure it is set at the correct depth?

Comment: Is the box already anchored? If so a simple box extension that looks like a bell box. Bell boxes are not well suited for old work but I would use a device called battleships they will work on the top side for old work, you have to rebuild the wall for them to work on the bottom side but that would be just about the only way to use a bell box without drilling holes in it and trying to mount other ways.

Comment: The box is not anchored. I think it is a bell box

Comment: I thought it was a bell box use battleships , just google most pros use them, not hard to learn watch a utube and learn in 2 minutes unless some likes to hear themselves talk then it could take longer.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a weather proof box. The box is surface mounted. The short sides of the box have round indents where a mounting pin is inserted. One end of the pin is round and the other has a flat tab with a hole for a screw. The tabs come with the box. If you are going to use this box, you have to pull it out from the wall and anchor it to the sheet rock or brick using the proper anchor. Looking at the picture it appears that this is an inside wall. You could change the box to a 4 inch square box and surface mount that, or use a duplex box in the wall and support it with Madison bars. I think it would be difficult to use an extension on this box in its current location in the wall because you have to put the ears on the box and anchor to brick and have the box mounted level.